# BAT File - START not working randomly on some Windows 7 machines

Tags: windows-7, path, set, startup

I have a bat file I'm using to start up GoogleChromePortable and open a web page in Kiok mode.

It works great on my machine and 3 others, except for one where it alerts me that the .exe cannot be found i.e. the path set is not working. Here's the code:

```
@echo off
set path=%path%;"./folder/chromeFolder"
START /b GoogleChromePortable.exe --kiosk "../../../../index.html"
```

I run this off a usb.
The ../../../../index.html is there because chrome starts 4 layers deep in the folder structure even though GoogleChromePortable is 3 above the Chrome.exe (might not be relevant).

Tested on 1*Windows8(worked), 1*Windows7(worked), 2*WindowsXP(worked) BUT 1*Windows7(Failed).

Error Message:
"Windows cannot find GoogleChromePortable.exe Make sure you typed the address correctly"

I have tried starting the BAT in administrator mode and this still did not work.

I have tried typing this in step by step and it's the

```
START GoogleChromePortable.exe
```

that is failing

---

SOLUTION

Right. Fixed it. No idea why this works so if anyone knows I'd love to know. Instead of the code above I've used:

```
START %~dp0folder/chrome/GoogleChromePortable.exe --kiosk "../../../../index.html"
```

and that's it. Any ideas why this works and the other method doesn't on 1 machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right. Fixed it. No idea why this works so if anyone knows I'd love to know. Instead of the code above I've used:

```
START %~dp0folder/chrome/GoogleChromePortable.exe --kiosk "../../../../index.html"
```

and that's it. Any ideas why this works and the other method doesn't on 1 machine?

Answer (score 0):

"3 above **IT**" - 3 above what?

You appear to be attempting to add ".\folder\chromefolder" to the path - perhaps it might be an idea to add the directory that is "3 above it" so that `GoogleChromePortable.exe` is also on the path - presumably on your USB.

Mayhap `GoogleChromePortable.exe` is already on the path on those other machines...

Comment: ChromePortable.exe starts at level 1 calling chrome.exe 3 layers down. My index.html starts above the entire folder at level 0 requireing the cmd prompt to be told to look 4 levels up

Comment: So if index.html is at `"..\..\..\..\index.html"` and from your comment, `Chromeportable.exe` is one layer down, then to have `chromeportable.exe` in the path, might it not be an idea to include `"..\..\..\"` in the path - or even execute `"..\..\..\chromeportable.exe"` - or `Googlechromeportable.exe` or whatever its name is? No idea where `chrome.exe` comes into the equation, but from what you've said, perhaps it's at `"..\"` - if that's relevant

Comment: Sorry I know it's hard to explain. It's how ChromePortable works.

Comment: I think I've found an answer but no idea why it works. If I uses START %-dp0folder/chrome/GoogleChromePortable.exe it works. I've love to know why this works and why the other method didn't on 1 machine

Comment: folder structure looks like this: Run.bat, index.html, /folder/chrome/GoogleChromePortable.exe, ./folder/chrome/folder/folder/chrome.exe